# Module "lspconfig not found"

Tags: lazy-evaluation, neovim, liskov-substitution-principle, nvim-lspconfig

I'm using Neovim, Lua, and Lazy.nvim. I've installed nvim-lspconfig, as this screenshot proves:
[Proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82ocd.png)

Anyway, I wanted to use GDScript in Neovim, and this is what I ended up doing this:

```lua
 -- General lsp setups for Language servers not supported by Mason.

local lsp = require("lspconfig")

lsp.godot.setup {
  cmd = { "nc", "localhost", "6008" },
  filetypes = { "gd", "gdscript", "gdscript3" },
  root_dir = function(startpath)
    return M.search_ancestors(startpath, matcher)
  end
}
```

I restart and everything, then I got an error.
It's your typical "no module found" error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsIS2.png)

It also broke my config, no commands (other than the ones that come with Neovim) work.

The thing is, I clearly installed `nvim-lspconfig` here's my lspconfig.lua file

```lua
return  {
    -- LSP Configuration & Plugins
    'neovim/nvim-lspconfig',
    dependencies = {
      -- Automatically install LSPs to stdpath for neovim
      {'williamboman/mason.nvim', config = true},
      'williamboman/mason-lspconfig.nvim',

      -- Useful status updates for LSP
      -- NOTE: `opts = {}` is the same as calling `require('fidget').setup({})`
      { 'j-hui/fidget.nvim', tag = 'legacy', opts = {} },

      -- Additional lua configuration, makes nvim stuff amazing!
      'folke/neodev.nvim',
    },
    config = function ()
      local on_attach = function(_, bufnr)
      -- NOTE: Remember that lua is a real programming language, and as such it is possible
      -- to define small helper and utility functions so you don't have to repeat yourself
      -- many times.
      --
      -- In this case, we create a function that lets us more easily define mappings specific
      -- for LSP related items. It sets the mode, buffer and description for us each time.
      local nmap = function(keys, func, desc)
        if desc then
          desc = 'LSP: ' .. desc
        end
      
        vim.keymap.set('n', keys, func, { buffer = bufnr, desc = desc })
      end
      

      nmap('<leader>rn', vim.lsp.buf.rename, '[R]e[n]ame')
      nmap('<leader>ca', vim.lsp.buf.code_action, '[C]ode [A]ction')

      nmap('gd', require('telescope.builtin').lsp_definitions, '[G]oto [D]efinition')
      nmap('gr', require('telescope.builtin').lsp_references, '[G]oto [R]eferences')
      nmap('gI', require('telescope.builtin').lsp_implementations, '[G]oto [I]mplementation')
      nmap('<leader>D', require('telescope.builtin').lsp_type_definitions, 'Type [D]efinition')
      nmap('<leader>ds', require('telescope.builtin').lsp_document_symbols, '[D]ocument [S]ymbols')
      nmap('<leader>ws', require('telescope.builtin').lsp_dynamic_workspace_symbols, '[W]orkspace [S]ymbols')

      -- See `:help K` for why this keymap
      nmap('K', vim.lsp.buf.hover, 'Hover Documentation')
      nmap('<C-k>', vim.lsp.buf.signature_help, 'Signature Documentation')

      -- Lesser used LSP functionality
      nmap('gD', vim.lsp.buf.declaration, '[G]oto [D]eclaration')
      nmap('<leader>wa', vim.lsp.buf.add_workspace_folder, '[W]orkspace [A]dd Folder')
      nmap('<leader>wr', vim.lsp.buf.remove_workspace_folder, '[W]orkspace [R]emove Folder')
      nmap('<leader>wl', function()
        print(vim.inspect(vim.lsp.buf.list_workspace_folders()))
        end, '[W]orkspace [L]ist Folders')
      -- Create a command `:Format` local to the LSP buffer
      vim.api.nvim_buf_create_user_command(bufnr, 'Format', function(_)
        vim.lsp.buf.format()
      end, { desc = 'Format current buffer with LSP' })
    end
    end

}
```

Gotten form kickstart.

I've tried asking ChatGPT, but ChatGPT can't seem to answer me correctly (all it's solutions are seemingly tied with Vim-Plug) So I decided to just ask on Stack Overflow, maybe someone who has overcome this issue can help.

Answer (score 0):

Even though I am not answering your question, to avoid this type of problems,
If you use mason.nvim and lspconfig, it is recommended that you use [mason-lspconfig.nvim] [1](https://github.com/williamboman/mason-lspconfig.nvim?tab=readme-ov-file), especially if you are using Windows.